# Neo4j - CASE DETACH DELETE error: Invalid input 'S'

Tags: neo4j, case-statement

I'm trying to detach delete on a specific case. I have the following query.

```
MATCH (childNode)-[r]-(parentNode)
CASE WHEN childNode.version = 1
THEN DETACH DELETE childNode, parentNode
ELSE DETACH DELETE childNode
RETURN childNode, parentNode
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 7, column 3 (offset: 425))
"CASE cv.version"
   ^
```

I don't understand why the issue is occurring. There doesn't seem to be invalid input to my knowledge. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CASE` can only be used in a `RETURN` or a `WITH` to translate one value to an other. You can't use a `CASE` to do a conditional query.

So in your case, I recommend you to make two queries :

```
MATCH (childNode {version:1})-[r]-(parentNode)
DETACH DELETE childNode, parentNode;

MATCH (childNode)-[r]-(parentNode)
DETACH DELETE childNode;
```